# Quadratic Reciprocity as an Analytic Statement

Tags: theta-functions, quadratic-reciprocity

I was told an interesting fact that quadratic reciprocity follows from the modularity of the theta function $\theta(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{2\pi in^{2}z}$:

$$\theta(\gamma z) = \left(\frac{c}{d}\right)\epsilon_{d}^{-1}(cz+d)^{1/2}\theta(z)$$

where $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_{0}(4)$, $\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)$ is the extended Jacobi symbol, and $\epsilon_{d}$ is the normalized Gauss sum attached to the quadratic character $(-/d)$. The idea is to set $z = -p/q+\epsilon$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. From this one get's the Landsberg-Schaar relation
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}\sum_{n = 0}^{p-1}e^{\frac{2\pi in^{2}q}{p}} = \frac{e^{\pi i/4}}{\sqrt{2q}}\sum_{n = 0}^{2q-1}e^{-\frac{\pi in^{2}p}{2q}}.$$
When $q = 1$ we get Gauss's evaulation of the quadratic gauss sum and quadratic reciprocity can be proven from this (this was the original post [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120067/what-do-theta-functions-have-to-do-with-quadratic-reciprocity)).

I'm curious about the converse question so to speak. That is, what can you prove about the theta function from quadratic reciprocity. I think it boils down to that the nebentypus

$$\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)\epsilon_{d}^{-1}$$

is a homomorphism. So if $\gamma' = \begin{pmatrix} a' & b' \\\ c' & d' \end{pmatrix}$ then this is equivalent to showing

$$\left(\frac{c'a+d'c}{c'b+d'd}\right)\epsilon_{d'd}^{-1} = \left(\frac{c'}{d'}\right)\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)\epsilon_{d'}^{-1}\epsilon_{d}^{-1}$$

because $c$ and $c'$ are equivalent to $0$ modulo $4$.

I've played around with this a lot and I can't seem to reduce it to quadratic reciprocity. Adding a multiple of the bottom of the symbol on the left to the top component doesnt do much because there is no information relating the primed letters to the nonprimed letters.

Comment: I'd suspect that QR is weaker than the assertions about theta functions... For that matter, QR is seemingly weaker than "Hilbert reciprocity" about quadratic Hilbert symbols. And, in my opinion, there is indeed a larger mechanism underlying these truths, so grabbing one easily-parsed "flower" does not promise that all the other things follow. :)

Comment: After going through the (quite tedious) verifiction that this is the correct factor of modularity, I agree with your comment. This seems like a much stronger (and suprising) result. Do you mind elaborating on "in my opinion, there is indeed a larger mechanism"? I'm not sure what you meant by this.

Comment: Weil's proof that the Segal-Shale-Weil/oscillator representation really is a representation, etc., implies this, and holds for a more structured reason, using the Stone-vonNeumann theorem to simplify computations. Adelic Poisson Summation enters. Lots of action... :)

Comment: Very interesting... Thank you, I appreciate it! :)